# Running script when Option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a calculator script who does some calculations in Insert Record form.
In order to run, i want it to check if option in a select dropdown menu, since i only want it to work, when specific items are selected through the drop menu. Here is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function KW_getVal(o){ //v1.2
var retVal="0";if (o.type=="select-one")
{retVal=(o.selectedIndex==-1)?0:o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;}
else if (o.length>1){for (var i=0;i<o.length;i++) if (o[i].checked) retVal=o[i].value;
} else if (o.type=="checkbox") {retVal=(o.checked)?o.value:0;} else {
retVal=Number(o.value)}return parseFloat(retVal);
}

function KW_calcForm() { //v1.2
var str="",a=KW_calcForm.arguments; for (var i=3;i<a.length;i++)
str+=(a[i].indexOf("#")==-1)?a[i]:KW_getVal(MM_findObj(a[i].substring(1)));
t=Math.round(a[1]*eval(str))/a[1];tS=t.toString();if(a[2]>0){tSp=tS.indexOf(".");
if(tSp==-1) tS+=".";tSp=tS.indexOf(".");while(tSp!=(tS.length-1-a[2])){tS+="0";
tSp=tS.indexOf(".");}} MM_findObj(a[0]).value=tS;
}
function KW_calcForm() { //v1.2
var str="",a=KW_calcForm.arguments; for (var i=3;i<a.length;i++)
str+=(a[i].indexOf("#")==-1)?a[i]:KW_getVal(MM_findObj(a[i].substring(1)));
t=Math.round(a[1]*eval(str))/a[1];tS=t.toString();if(a[2]>0){tSp=tS.indexOf(".");
if(tSp==-1) tS+=".";tSp=tS.indexOf(".");while(tSp!=(tS.length-1-a[2])){tS+="0";
tSp=tS.indexOf(".");}} MM_findObj(a[0]).value=tS;
}
 </script>
```

The script works perfect, but works on all selected options from the dropdown menu, which is

```
<td><select name="Operator">
    <option value="" <?php if (!(strcmp("", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>></option>
    <option value="Dani" <?php if (!(strcmp("Dani", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Dani</option>
    <option value="Costi" <?php if (!(strcmp("Costi", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Costi</option>
    <option value="Ioni" <?php if (!(strcmp("Ioni", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Ioni</option>
    <option value="Cristina" <?php if (!(strcmp("Cristina", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Cristina</option>
    <option value="Alex" <?php if (!(strcmp("Alex", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Alex</option>
    <option value="Roland" <?php if (!(strcmp("Roland", htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Operator'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Roland</option>
  </select></td>
```

Can i write some code to run this code when "Dani" is selected?
Like an "if or else" option to the script

I tried this but didint work.

```
if ( $("#Operator") == Dani ) {
```

Comment: `if ($("#Operator").val() == "Dani")` maybe?

Comment: i tried that, didint work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're using jQuery, how about something like this:

```
$('select[name="Operator"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Dani") {
        //do what you want here
    }    
});
```

The code above triggers on the change, i now think that was not what you meant.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/fwaam7at/

---

you may need this:

```
if($('[name="Operator"]') == "Dani") {}
```

In your own example you've used  '#Operator' as the selector, but with a # in jQuery you look for an ID and not a Name.

Comment: Tried this too, didint work, maybe i shouldnt use jQuery

Comment: I have edited my answer because I think i've misunderstood your original question